# Issue with RegularExpressionValidator

Tags: c#, validation

I have a problem with the RegularExpressionValidator. This seems to be issues with the validator itself.

The problem occurs with Firefox because it has an autocomplete dropdown, however it could also have the same issue on other browsers.

**Problem 1**
If I focus inside a textbox, Firefoxes autocomplete displays. If I highlight a valid entry but press enter rather than say tab, a validation error occurs, even though the value is correct.

If I tab outside the textbox the message resets.

**Problem 2**
If I repeat the process that caused problem 1, by focusing back into the textbox letting firefox display auto complete and pressing enter again, the same problem occurs however this time the validator is not cleared when focus moves outside the textbox and the error message remains visible.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is related to the fact that you're pressing the Enter key, which causes a postback.  When the page posts, it sends the state of each control at the time you pressed Enter, so the value you chose from the autocomplete dropdown wasn't populated yet.  My recommendation would be to disable the Enter key when the textbox has the focus.

You can find an example of that [here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/articles/disable-enter-key-in-textbox-to-avoid-postback-in-asp.net.aspx).

Comment: Matt - thanks for the reply - it turns out that its actually a Firefox bug that is not handled well in Asp.Net. No postback because this is happening client side. When enter is pressed firefox only reads the first character of the value and therefore it is incorrect as far as the regular expression is concerned.